# Vec of struct with lifetimes

Tags: rust, struct, lifetime

I'm trying to use [RustyBuzz](https://docs.rs/rustybuzz/latest/rustybuzz/) to do some text display. Shaping is done by a struct called `Face<'a>` which contains a reference to bytes from a font file. I would like to allow for loading fonts "on the fly", e.g. a user inputs a path to a font file, the file is loaded, a new `Face<'a>` is created and added to a container for fonts. How can I create such a font container, given the lifetime parameter in `Face<'a>`?

Naïvely, one would do something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct FontAtlas<'a> {
   fonts : Vec<Face<'a>>
}

impl<'a> FontAtlas<'a> {
   fn add_new_font(&mut self, bytes : &'a [u8]) {
       self.fonts.push(Face::from_slice(bytes, 0).unwrap());
   }
}
```

Then schematically, in a main function:

```rust
fn main() {
   let mut atlas = FontAtlas::default();
   loop {
      let font_path  = get_user_input();
      let font_bytes = std::fs::read(font_path).unwrap();
      atlas.add_new_font(&font_bytes);
   }
}
```

This does not work because `atlas` outlives `font_bytes`. One could make `font_bytes` longer-lived like so:

```rust
fn main() {
   let mut font_data : Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new(); // holds all bytes from font files
   let mut atlas = FontAtlas::default();

   loop {
      let font_path  = get_user_input();
      let font_bytes = std::fs::read(font_path).unwrap();
      font_data.push(font_bytes); // mutable borrow invalidates all refs in atlas
      atlas.add_new_font(font_data.last().unwrap()); // 'font_data.last()' will live longer than 'atlas', so we're good on this side
   }
}
```

But with the lifetime restrictions, this violates borrowing rules: `font_data` must be borrowed immutably for the whole `loop`, which prevents the mutable borrow needed to push to `font_data`.

Is there any way I can achieve font loading "on the fly"? Or is this intrinsically "unsafe"?

Comment: how do you use a `Face` ? Do you use more than one `Face` at the same time ?

Comment: You call a method on a string. To simplify: `font.shape(text)`. In my use case, you would loop over chunks of text ; each chunk is "shaped" by one and only one of the fonts.

Comment: It's a shame that the library doesn't take a `Cow<'a, [u8]>` instead because then you could just give ownership to the `Face`. Maybe it's worth submitting a feature request?

Comment: I agree ! The problem actually comes from the struct `Face` of the downstream crate `ttf_parser`, which `Face` is a wrapper around.

Comment: You need to bring up this problem to the crates maintainers. There is unsafe solution but that a very bad idea. Currently my advice is to store your data in the vec `Vec<Vec<u8>>` and create the face every time you need it.

Comment: @cdhowie why do you so aggressively talk to me about a solution that just leak memory ? I never say leak memory was unsafe xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but you can [leak a `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) to get a reference with `'static` lifetime:

```
fn main() {
   let mut atlas = FontAtlas::default();
   loop {
      let font_path  = get_user_input();
      let font_bytes = Box::leak(std::fs::read(font_path).unwrap().into_boxed_slice());
      atlas.add_new_font(font_bytes);
   }
}
```

This assumes that the byte data must exist for the entire duration of the program.

You can wrap up this basic idea to create a safe abstraction of a "registry of owned byte slices" that also cleans up its own allocations:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

#[derive(Default)]
struct ByteRegistry(RefCell<Vec<*mut [u8]>>);

impl ByteRegistry {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
    
    // Note this can take self by shared reference due to the use of RefCell.
    pub fn add(&self, bytes: impl Into<Box<[u8]>>) -> &[u8] {
        let data = Box::into_raw(bytes.into());
        self.0.borrow_mut().push(data);
        
        // SAFETY: We own the data, and the reference is tied to our lifetime,
        // so it will be released before we are dropped.
        unsafe { &*data }
    }
}

impl Drop for ByteRegistry {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for data in self.0.take().into_iter() {
            // SAFETY: We obtained the pointers from Box::into_raw() and all
            // borrows from add() have ended by now.
            unsafe { drop(Box::from_raw(data)) }
        }
    }
}
```